# How to Pass a System.Data.DataSet Object as an Argument to a Powershell Workflow?

Tags: powershell

I'm getting some data from a SQL table, which I then store in a `System.Data.DataSet` object. I want to pass this data in this DataSet, as an Argument/Parameter, to a `workflow`, such that I can display all the data in this DataSet in a `foreach -parallel` style. But I'm at a loss for the correct syntax of passing data from a `System.Data.DataSet` object to a `workflow`. Currently I get an Error near the line "*param([System.Data.DataSet]$pServiceDataSet)*" as shown below.

[image]

```
Function GetSQLData
{
    param ($TargetDBServer, $TargetDB, $SQLQuery)
    
    # SQL Connection Object
    $sqlConn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
    $sqlConn.ConnectionString = "Server=$TargetDBServer;Database=$TargetDB;User Id=SomeUser;Password=SomePassword;"
    $sqlConn.Open()
    
    # SQL Command
    $sqlcmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
    $sqlcmd.Connection = $sqlConn
    $sqlcmd.CommandText = $SQLQuery
    
    # SQL Adapter
    $sqlAdp = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter ($sqlcmd)
    
    # SQL DataSet
    $ResultDataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
    $sqlAdp.Fill($ResultDataSet) | Out-Null
    $sqlConn.Close()
    
    return $ResultDataSet.Tables[0]
}

$CurrentComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME

# Export the Windows Services & it's config parameters from the "DatabaseABC..WindowsServicesConfig" Table.
$SQLQueryForService = "
SELECT [ServiceName], [StartUpParameter], [DBServerName], [DBName]
FROM [dbo].[WindowsServicesConfig] WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE [HostServerName] = '$CurrentComputerName'
      AND [ServiceName] LIKE '%MyService%' "
$ServicesDataSet = GetSQLData -TargetDBServer "ServerABC" -TargetDB "DatabaseABC" -SQLQuery $SQLQueryForService

$ServicesDataSet.GetType()
$ServicesDataSet | Format-Table

workflow DisplayAllServices
{
    param([System.Data.DataSet]$pServiceDataSet)    # <- I get an Error here
    
    foreach -parallel ($Service in $pServiceDataSet)
    {
        $Service.ServiceName
        $Service.StartUpParameter
        $Service.DBServerName
        $Service.DBName
    }
}

DisplayAllServices -pServiceDataSet $ServicesDataSet
```

My final objective is to use the data in this DataSet to create Windows Services. But this is my most frustrating hurdle. I cannot get past the Error.

Comment: You're specifying the parameter to be a DataSet when the object is actually an array.

Comment: Figured out the Solution to my Problem. Replaced the "param([System.Data.DataSet]$pServiceDataSet)" with "param([PSObject]$pServiceDataSet)".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the Solution to my Problem. Replaced the "param([System.Data.DataSet]$pServiceDataSet)" with "param([PSObject]$pServiceDataSet)".